# RHmm installation Errors

Tags: software-installation, c++, r

I am trying to install RHmm on Ubuntu and I have the following error. Any help will be appreciated. Best, ilyas.

```
:~/Desktop/RHmm/src$ g++ -c *.cpp
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cBaumWelch.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cBaumWelchInParam.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cDerivative.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cDiscrete.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from cDMatrix.cpp:11:0:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cDVector.cpp: In member function ‘void cDVector::Initialize(uint)’:
cDVector.cpp:16:34: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 { myAssert(mvV == NULL, "Problem") ;
                              ^
cDVector.cpp: In function ‘cDVector operator+(const cDVector&, const cDVector&)’:
cDVector.cpp:297:92: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   myAssert(myN==theRightVect.GetSize(), "operator +: vectors must have the same dimensions") ;
                                                                                        ^
cDVector.cpp: In function ‘cDVector operator+=(cDVector&, const cDVector&)’:
cDVector.cpp:307:95: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   myAssert(myN == theRightVect.GetSize(), "operator +=: vectors must have the same dimensions") ;
                                                                                           ^
cDVector.cpp: In function ‘cDVector operator-(const cDVector&, const cDVector&)’:
cDVector.cpp:316:95: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   myAssert( myN == theRightVect.GetSize(), "operator -: vectors must have the same dimensions") ;
                                                                                           ^
cDVector.cpp: In function ‘cDVector operator-=(cDVector&, const cDVector&)’:
cDVector.cpp:326:95: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   myAssert(myN == theRightVect.GetSize(), "operator -=: vectors must have the same dimensions") ;
                                                                                           ^
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cHmm.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cHmmFit.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cInParam.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cLogBaumWelch.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cMixtMultivariateNormal.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cMixtUnivariateNormal.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cMultivariateNormal.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cRUtils.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cUnivariateNormal.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from cViterbi.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from Kmeans.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from Main.cpp:14:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from MultivariateNormalUtil.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from RHmm.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from SamplesUtil.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from StatUtil.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from OTMathUtil.h:17:0,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.h:11,
                 from StdAfxRHmm.cpp:11:
cDMatrix.h:23:26: fatal error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: The install the package from a local source tarball use `R CMD INSTALL RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz`

Comment: It does not help. Some header files R missing and I do not know how to install or download them.

Comment: can you show us the error message of `R CMD INSTALL`?

Comment: [Problem Solved] I did it again to get the error and worked now!!!. R CMD INSTALL RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz! Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to install the the local source tarball:

Command line:

```
R CMD INSTALL RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz
```

or in R:

```
install.packages("RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```